# 1950s story about faster than light ships that disappear

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for a 1950s story about faster than light ships that disappear due to acceleration of the aging process?

This was a library book. The plot involved space travel, and the development of a Faster Than Light drive. The problem is that ships disappear. A young man, a chemist, becomes involved. At some point, he realises that the ships are disappearing because as the ships approach the speed of light the aging process in people accelerates. He starts looking for a formula to counteract the acceleration, and at the last minute finds the formulae saving his and the crew's life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a short story?  When did you read it?  Was it in a magazine or anthology?  Do the ships break down and disintegrate, or by what other mechanism do they "disappear?"